# How to extract data from HREF attribute in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I recorded steps in jmeter and it requires 3 parameters to be passed to a url in GET method. In currently loaded page these values are in href attribute and I need to extract those values from that href attibute and then populate parameters Reference, QReference, PartId, type.

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: DisplayUrl() }" target="_blank" href="/Display/GetDisplayView?Reference=URamI5yhouguHKqx86RFXA**&amp;QReference=THhfW04ZpJxC1D0AVX14pw**&amp;PartId=jze7XeL_fIM5L5lcGQCv53jUFe8yRvKV_aUQCJ4dJRzAI0s3grkfM9qxgyTgSts3&amp;type=ebayDi49bY2kXrAQdf64wg**&amp;_=sK8FCsmYiq6YKLOnGu_s34CFScum6KwX5m_7v_7glbc*">
                    <img data-bind="attr: { src: OpenInNewWindowIcon() }" style="border:0;float:left;padding-left:8px;" src="../../Content/Themes/Images/Summary/icon-new-small-window.gif">
                </a>
```

How can I extract http value with Regular Expression Extractor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add Regular Expression Extractor after GET Sampler.

Patterns will look like:

```
QReference=(.+?);
PartId=(.+?);
type=(.+?);
```